# Large messages handling with 'sqs-extended-jar'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I want to use Amazon SQS extended client jar to send and receive messages larger than 256 KB. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/s3-messages.html

As mentioned in the example in above link, we need to create queue using 
AmazonSQS sqsExtended = new AmazonSQSExtendedClient(new AmazonSQSClient(credentials), extendedClientConfig);

My question is : 
How does it handle messages less than 256 KB, Does it internally also stores those messages  in s3 or directly store the messages in the queue itself ?.

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Did anyone get a chance to look at this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked states:

Specifically, you use this library to:

- Specify whether messages are always stored in Amazon S3 or only when a message's size exceeds 256 KB.

This setting is set via ExtendedClientConfiguration class (alwaysThroughS3 attribute). It is false by default, you can set it e.g. by using withAlwaysThroughS3 method.

(https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/ExtendedClientConfiguration.java)

In the example, you can force the flag using the following code:

```
    // Set the SQS extended client configuration with large payload support enabled.
    ExtendedClientConfiguration extendedClientConfig = new ExtendedClientConfiguration()
      .withLargePayloadSupportEnabled(s3, s3BucketName)
      .withAlwaysThroughS3(True);
```